# Немного вопросов о многопоточности

Tags: java, многопоточность

Сам не первый год пишу на java, но лишь в рамках хобби, с многопоточностью приходится не так часто работать.

Заинтересовали несколько вопросов, а имённо:

1. Допустим, мне нужно **писать и вычитывать примитивный тип на каком-то объекте (из разных потоков)**. Допустим, поля открытые (`public`).

   Если верить справке java, операции чтения и записи ссылок являются **атомарными** (логично, ведь размер такой ссылки обычно помещается в регистр процессора, да и система его поддерживает).  Тогда чтение и запись поля, хранящего ссылку на объект, вполне себе нормальная операция для выполнения в разных потоках.

   Также справка java уверяет, что чтение и запись примитивных типов, исключая `long` и `double`, тоже являются атомарными. Но как быть с этими двумя? Как я понимаю, их нужно лишь пометить как `volatile`. **Но есть ли какие-то побочные эффекты, или этот модификатор только и делает, что гарантирует атомарность операций над переменной?**

   Хорошо. А теперь, к примеру, я хочу читать и писать поля через геттеры-сеттеры. Если мои геттеры-сеттеры не меняют состояние каких-либо внешних данных, а лишь читают и пишут переменную, **достаточно ли мне пометить такую переменную как `volatile`, или же нужно отмечать геттер/сеттер как `syncronized`?** (При условии, что доступ к переменным возможен лишь через геттер и сеттер).
2. Работа с объектами. А конкретно, с объектами, что не меняют состояния.

   К примеру, `String`. Насколько мне известно, данный тип никогда **не меняет состояния**, а все его методы, возвращающие строку, возвращают новый экземпляр.

   **Так вот, могу ли я обращаться к такому объекту из разных потоков без дополнительной синхронизации?** Или же я могу тогда что-то упустить (вопрос для случая, когда я могу лишь получить объект, но не изменить значение поля, на него ссылающегося).

Благодарю за терпение того, кто сможет на эти вопросы ответить)

Comment: @selya старайтесь избегать таких сборных вопросов. Одна проблема - один пост.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Важно, что `volatile` гарантирует видимость. Изменения volatile-поля в одном потоке будут сразу видны в другом. Если вам нужно потокобезопасно выполнить более сложную процедуру, чем присвоение - воспользуйтесь synchronized или `j.u.c.Atomic*`-типами, чтобы избежать возникновения гонок (race condition).

   Пример: любой многопоточный счетчик

   ```
   // Плохо 
   private volatile long counter;

   public long getId() { 
       counter += 1;
       return counter;
   }

   // Хорошо
   private volatile AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);

   public long getId() { 
       return counter.incrementAndGet();
   }

   // Тоже хорошо
   private volatile long counter;

   public synchronized long getId() { 
       counter += 1;
       return counter;
   }
   ```

   Помните, что `synchronized` - это всегда явная блокировка (но она довольно дёшева при низкой конкуренции), а Atomic-примитивы используют бесконечный цикл с CAS-инструкциями и могут хорошо оптимизироваться.

---

2. Объекты с неизменяемым состоянием (например, все поля такого объекта `final`) назвают immutable объектами, и с ними безопасно работать из разных потоков. Но если внутреннее состояние объекта содержит изменяемый какой-то компонент и он как-то может быть доступен снаружи - придется дополнительно думать о потокобезопасности. Пример:

   ```
   // потокобезопасный класс 
   public final class SafeFoo { 
       private final Date date = new Date();
   }


   // не потокобезопасный класс 
   public final class UnsafeFoo { 
       private final Date date = new Date();
       public Date getDate() { return date; }
   }
   ```

   Первый класс полностью потокобезопасен. Второй - нет. Метод `getDate()` осуществляет публикацию внутреннего состояния внешнему коду (unsafe publication). И где-то снаружи можно сделать так, изменив внутренне состояние:

   ```
   unsafeFoo.getDate().setHours(0);
   ```

   Защититься от этого можно, например созданием копии:

   ```
   // потокобезопасный класс 
   public final class SafeAgainFoo { 
       private final Date date = new Date();
       public Date getDate() { return date.clone(); }
   }
   ```

Comment: Насчёт п.1 есть [это](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) (Reads and writes are atomic for allvariables declared volatile (including long and double variables)), где вполне понятно написано о гарантии атомарности. (Как я понимаю, это больше последствие видимости в разных потоках, но все же это описано). В плане "более сложная операция" вы имеете в виду "сложить, отнять и потом прибавить", а не "прибавить", "инкремент" и т.д.? (С `Atomic` приходилось иметь дело в лямбдах,.ибо обращаться к `not-final` переменной, что находится вне лямбды, нельзя.

Comment: @selya , плохо выразился. Важно не то, что оно гарантирует атомарность, а видимость.

Comment: Да, так, пожалуй, лучше

Comment: @selya немного дополнил примером.

Comment: *В плане "более сложная операция" вы имеете в виду "сложить, отнять и потом прибавить", а не "прибавить", "инкремент" и т.д.?* Инкремент, кстати, не атомарен - имейте в виду.

Comment: да, об этом постоянно забываю. Понятное дело, постинкремент не атомарен, но вот с преинкрементом все чуть менее явно)

Comment: Хотелось бы все же узнать о каком-то примере, когда точно следует использовать `Atomic*` вместо обычных примитивных типов, а так вполне хорошо написано.

Comment: @selya , когда вам нужно атомарно выполнить что-то из того, что умеет Atomic - лучше брать Atomic (добавил пример).

Comment: Хм, про момент с принципом работы `Atomic*`-примитивов не знал, довольно познавательно. Спасибо